# Tailwind - How to add transitions to headless UI tabs

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3, tailwind-css, headless-ui

Is it possible to use transitions for [headlessui tabs](https://headlessui.com/vue/tabs#basic-example)? I'm using `@headlessui/vue`

```html
<template>
  <TabGroup>
    <TabList>
      <Tab>Tab 1</Tab>
      <Tab>Tab 2</Tab>
      <Tab>Tab 3</Tab>
    </TabList>
    <TabPanels>
      <TabPanel v-slot={selected} v-for="p in panels">
        <TransitionRoot :show="selected" enter...leave..>
          {{ p.content }}
        </TransitionRoot>
      </TabPanel>
    </TabPanels>
  </TabGroup>
</template>
```

This is a simplified example to show how I tried it. If I moved the Transition outside of the TabGroup, it works fine. But when inside, the transition doesn't happen.

Are headless UI components not possible to nest? Am I doing it wrong?

Comment: See https://github.com/tailwindlabs/headlessui/discussions/1301

Answer (score 0):

Your code looks correct to me.
It is possible to nest headless UI components and animate the enter phase of a tab like this:

```
<TabPanel as="template" v-slot="{ selected }" :unmount="false">
  <TransitionRoot :show="selected" enter="tab-enter" enter-to="tab-enter-to" :unmount="false" enter-from="tab-enter-from">
    Tab Content
  </TransitionRoot>
</TabPanel>


<style scoped lang="scss">
  .tab-enter {
    transition: all 0.5s ease-in;
  }

  .tab-enter-from {
    opacity: 0.5;
    transform: translateX(100px);
  }

  .tab-enter-from {
    opacity: 0.5;
    transform: translateX(-100px);
  }

  .tab-enter-to {
    opacity: 1;
    transform: translateX(0);
  }
  </style>
```

Please double check if you imported the Components correctly:

```
<script lang="ts" setup>
  import { Tab, TabGroup, TabList, TabPanel, TabPanels, TransitionRoot } from '@headlessui/vue';
</script>
```

Unfortunately the exit is not animatable so easily because the tab will be hidden immediately. You can, however overwrite the `display: none;` of the `[hidden]` attribute and have your own absolute positioned logic.